# How to Get Html from a Url in Android API 16?

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am a newer to Android,this question,I have tried many times, but I can't do it. Pls help!

This is my code:

```
public class HttpHelper {
private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30000;
private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 10000;

public static String GET(String uri) {
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpResponse response;
    String data = "";

    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            data = out.toString();
        } else {
            // Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {

    } catch (IOException e) 
    {

    }
    return data;
}
```

}

I Call the Method like this:

```
TextView jaxrs = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jaxrs);
String result = HttpHelper.GET("http://www.baidu.com/");
jaxrs.setContentDescription(result);
```

When I ran this app,it alert "Unfortunately,* has stopped."

Guys,logcat,I cant upload images,So paste this.

```
01-06 20:35:10.404: E/Trace(1102): error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2)    
01-06 20:35:10.904: D/AndroidRuntime(1102): Shutting down VM    
01-06 20:35:10.914: W/dalvikvm(1102): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): FATAL EXCEPTION: main    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibelieve.news/com.ibelieve.news.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)    
01-06 20:35:10.924: E/AndroidRuntime(1102):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
```

Comment: pls post your logcat here.

Comment: post your logcat, what error you are getting in your logcat.

Comment: Thanks to all very much,I know.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing network activity in that Activity on the **Main UI thread**. This will raise an `exception`. To fix it move the network operation (GET request) to it's own [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html) or an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).